# Запятые в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Люди добрые! Помогите определить,где границы придаточного предложения? Нужна ли запятая после "в стране" или после "2015 г."?

Как и что будет после введения новых технологических регламентов Таможенного Союза (далее — ТР ТС) в 2015 г. в сложившейся политической и экономической ситуации в стране  однозначно ответить сложно, однако предполагаю, что динамика будет положительная, т. к. уже существующие регламенты ориентированы на отечественные компании для обеспечения им преимущества в рамках ВТО.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По_моему,смысл предложения в том,что в сложившихся условиях трудно однозначно сказать о судьбе в 2015 году новых технологических регламентов Таможенного союза,поэтому придаточное предложение заканчивается словами "в 2015 году"

Comment: Да, наверное, Вы правы. Хотя я сначала склонялась к запятой после "в стране".